# How to use connection string with sequel for postgresql

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I wanted to connect to postgresql database using connection string in form of

```
host=localhost user=x password=y dbname=z
```

this works fine when passed to psql

```
$ psql "host=localhost user=x password=y dbname=z"
```

and when passed to the `PG` gem

```
> PG.connect("host=localhost user=x password=y dbname=z")
```

however it fails when I try to pass it into sequel

```
> Sequel.postgres(constr)
Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError: PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
```

How can I make sequel connect to my database?

Comment: Is your app a rails application?

Comment: combination of hanami and grape if it helps

Answer (score 1):

You could use a string with the connection information, for example:

```
conn_str = 'postgres://localhost/database_name?user=user&password=password'


DB = Sequel.connect(conn_str)
```

Check the Sequel's documentation of [how to open connections](https://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/opening_databases_rdoc.html) with a hash

```
DB = Sequel.connect(
  adapter: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'database_name',
  user: 'database_user',
  password: 'password'
)
```

Then you should be able to run:

```
DB[:table_name].where(:attribute => 5000..10000)
```

Or you could use the postgres method directly:

```
DB = Sequel.postgres('my_db', :user => 'user', :password => 'password', :host => 'localhost')
```

Check [devhints](https://devhints.io/sequel) open connection shortcuts

Comment: Yeah I know about this way, but I get connection string formatted as in my question from the environment and wanted to avoid having to parse it :/